# How to render Vue's main app to the body element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am building an admin page in a project that uses a paid-for theme called "pages".

The issue is that in these themes, `<nav>` and `<header>` must be direct children of `<body>`.

When I use Vue to bootstrap the app, I am rendering it to a `<div>` with an `id` that's set to `root`. This then nests the `<nav>` and `<header>` within this container (i.e. under `<div id="root">`).

I have been searching high and low on how to get Vue components to become direct children of body.

How to do this?

---

What I am getting:

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <nav></nav>
        <header></header>
    </div>
</body>
```

What the theme needs:

```html
<body>
    <nav></nav>
    <header></header>
</body>
```

Comment: Is your theme using child selectors from `body`? (e.g. `body > div`) . Vue doesn't like you mounting to the body tag.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With Vue 2.0 you cannot mount root instance to the body or html element.  You will be getting `[Vue warn]: Do not mount Vue to <html> or <body> - mount to normal elements instead.` error message.

> The provided element merely serves as a mounting point. Unlike in Vue 1.x, the mounted element will be replaced with Vue-generated DOM in all cases. It is therefore not recommended to mount the root instance to `<html>` or `<body>`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#el

The way around is to manually move your element on component `mount()` event.

```
<div id="app">
  <navbar :msg="msg"></navbar>
    
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    
  <button @click="msg = 'tested'">Test 2-way binding</button>
</div>
```

Example workflow:

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
  data: {
    msg: 'message'
  },
  components: {
    'navbar': {
      template: `<navbar>{{ msg }}</navbar>`,
      props: ['msg'],
      mounted() {
        document.body.insertBefore(this.$el, document.body.firstChild)
      }
    }
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jedrzejchalubek/m9dnsjjr/2/

Answer (score 10):

With Vue 3 you can do it.

```js
let YourApp = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'Hello World!'
    }
  },
  template: `
      <nav>Nav</nav>
      <header>Header</header>
      <span> inspect to see it</span>
  `
}

// Browser Version - vue.global.js
Vue.createApp(YourApp).mount('body')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.2/dist/vue.global.min.js"></script>
```